# Access return value of Bash script in Vim

Tags: linux, bash, shell, vim

I want to have a function in my .vimrc that will run a bash script, check the output, and do different things depending on the bash script output.

Currently, my bash script returns "yes". My vim function is then:

```
function! Callscript()

  if 'r ! . test.sh' == 'yes'
    echom "returned yes"
  else
    echom "returned something else"
  endif
endfunction
```

This will always print "returned something else". When I run the command ':r ! . test.sh', it returns:

```
test.sh: line 5: return: yes: numeric argument required
```

I didn't see anything in :help r! that mentioned doing anything extra to get the return values, but I tried:

```
  if 'r ! . test.sh'.return == 'yes'
  if 'r ! . test.sh':return == 'yes'
```

which gave me errors. I have tried using system, but could not get that to work. The most obvious approach I tried with system was:

```
  if system('r ! . test.sh') == 'yes'
```

When I try system('. test.sh') in the editor, it tells me system is not an editor command.

How can I access the return value of the bash script so that I can use it in my vim function?

Comment: What does 'my bash script returns "yes"' mean? Usually processes return an [tag:exit-code], rather than a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
>   if 'r ! . test.sh' == 'yes'
> ```

That syntax is nonsense. First, the `:r !{cmd}` is reading the output of `{cmd}` into the current buffer, which is probably not what you want. To get this into a variable, use `:let output = system('test.sh')`, or directly compare via:

```
if system('test.sh') == 'yes'
```

Note that comparing the output (especially if it's a true / false or success / failure boolean value as suggested by your question) is unusual. Rather, the script's *exit status* is checked (e.g. with commands like `grep`). You can get that in Vim via the special `v:shell_error` variable (which is filled by both `system()` and `:r !`).

Comment: I see. Thank you for the information. I have changed the bash script to have an exit code of 1 or 0 and changed the vim script if to 
call system('. test.sh') 
if v:shell_error == 1